# ASP.NET MVC List of Web Components in Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model

I need to get dynamically a list of Web Controls from View to be used in the model(dropdownlists, inputs, checkboxes, ...). Is it possible? I generate the controls in Razor.
My application should store last values of all controls for each user into the database and use them as predefined values for the next call of the form.
Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: The question is confusing. Do you want the values that those controls hold or you want the controls ?

Comment: Sounds like a really complicated way of storing page state across sessions!

Comment: I need the values of those controls to be stored in db. And later loaded and set to those controls again. By the next form call.

Comment: @Radek: Storing posted form values in a database is covered by pretty much every introductory tutorial for ASP.NET MVC.  What have you tried and how is it not working?

Answer (score 3):

> I need to get dynamically a list of Web Controls from View to be used in the model

First of all, you're probably going to find MVC a lot easier to understand if you abandon terms like "web controls" and the like.  Your view, which may not may not be utilizing helpers to do so, is simply building HTML.  Nothing more.

But more to the point, what you're proposing is exactly the *opposite* of what MVC does.  Your model should have *no knowledge* of the structure of the view.  (inputs, selects, other form elements, etc.)  The model contains the data and business logic necessary to render the view.  The *view* then uses that data and logic to build its interface.

You can post the *values* from the resulting HTML form to a server-side action.  Then from that action you can store those values in a database or do whatever you like with them.  If the key/value pairs of those values can logically be structured into the form of a model then the action can accept that model as a parameter, if not then it can also just as easily accept parameters for each individual value.  (Though if you find yourself using a lot of parameters it would be better to build a simple view model just to encapsulate them.)

The order of operations is something like:

1. A request is made to a controller action.
2. That controller action invokes logic on a model and provides that model to a view.
3. The view binds its UI elements to the model's data and renders the interface.
4. The user interacts with the interface and uses it to perform a request to another controller action.
5. That controller action receives the data from that request, performs server-side logic, etc.
6. and so on...

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your response. What is the result of it. Is it possible to meet the requirements I got or not? Thanks, Radek

Comment: @Radek: Depends on the requirements, which you haven't really specified clearly.  Your views can include form values which post data to controller actions, that's part of the base functionality of ASP.NET MVC.  (And indeed *any* web framework.)  What *exactly* are you trying to do and how is it not working for you?

Comment: Hello David, I have to implement "user dependent default values". Checkboxes, Inouts and all other elements should be prefilled with values from db. I should create a semiautomatic solution. Db records identified by viewName-elementName-propertyName. I need to load stored values for all elements in the view and assign them to the appropriate element later. Unfortunatelly I do not know how. Thank you for your help. Radek

Comment: @Radek: Literally *almost any* ASP.NET MVC tutorial is going to cover this scenario.  Almost every tutorial shows how to display data from a database and save data back to that database.  It sounds like you need to start with some introductory tutorials on the platform you're using (ASP.NET MVC).  The functionality you ask for is fundamental to every use case of that platform.

Comment: Hello David, the problem is really not about db introduction. I have about thousand of elemnts in my app. I have to manually administer the list of views and its corresponding elements (to be able to load and set their values from db). I need to automate this process and get the list of elements generated in the view automatically.

Comment: @Radek: I think you're missing a fundamental concept here.  As far as the model or controller is concerned, it *doesn't matter* how dynamically the view is rendered.  As long as the result of that rendering creates a form which can post those values back to the controller then those values will be send to the controller.  The model doesn't dynamically read the view, it just encapsulates the structure of the data.  You'd build your model (or auto-generate it from some template, perhaps), build your view to display what's in that model (or generate it), and create controller actions.

Comment: @Radek: Whatever it is you're trying to do is *very* unclear within the structural concepts of MVC.  It really sounds like you've started down the path of a *very* incorrect design and you're asking us how to continue down that path.  That's not going to be a very fruitful approach since it's based on incorrect assumptions.  (http://publicvoidlife.blogspot.com/2013/10/the-left-turn-at-albuquerque.html)